# Gnuplot: How to plot different symbols and name them

Tags: gnuplot

Here is my data and the pic after plotting using Gnuplot.

I used this command to do the pic. "plot "aaa.txt" with linespoints pt 6 ps 2 "

I just wondering how can I get the pic I want.

Request:

1. give different symbols to the points in the first and second rows of each block.
2. give different names to the points in the first and second rows and display them in the upper right corner

```
    60 18 
    59 20 
    
    60 18 
    67 25 
     
    60 18 
    77 11 
     
    60 18 
    67 10 
     
    60 18 
    53 18 
     
    60 18 
    83 6 
     
    60 18 
    80 16 
     
    60 18 
    71 14 
     
    60 18 
    68 1 
     
    60 18 
    76 3 
     
    92 95 
    97 94 
     
    92 95 
    95 98 
     
    92 95 
    98 76 
     
    92 95 
    96 96 
     
    92 95 
    80 97 
     
    10 71 
    33 80 
     
    10 71 
    39 95 
     
    10 71 
    26 78 
     
    10 71 
    14 61 
     
    10 71 
    29 80 
     
    10 71 
    39 98 
     
    10 71 
    0 46 
     
    10 71 
    12 71 
     
    10 71 
    10 96 
     
    10 71 
    18 66 
     
    10 71 
    20 89 
     
    10 71 
    30 97 
     
    10 71 
    39 84 
     
    10 71 
    1 45 
     
    10 71 
    4 62 
     
    10 71 
    21 65 
     
    34 40 
    25 53 
     
    34 40 
    31 60 
     
    34 40 
    5 31 
     
    34 40 
    14 31 
     
    34 40 
    40 52 
     
    34 40 
    14 32 
     
    34 40 
    41 30 
     
    34 40 
    41 53
```

The pic I already got:
[image: the pic I already got]

The pic I want
[image: the pic I want]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this is a good start:

```
plot 'data' w l lc rgb "black"  notitle, '' every ::::0 w p pt 7 lc rgb "black" ps 2 title "data a", '' every ::1 w p pt 2 lc rgb "black" ps 2 title "data b"
```

which gives:

[image]